# Commit to RiouxSVN fails

Tags: svn, authentication, commit, linux-mint

I'm with this stucked since yesterday. I know there are some topics about this, but nothing has worked.

I created a repository and still I cannot do the first commit.
Also, cannot checkout; I could only checkout the project by make the url public.

I have an account in RiouxSVN.com

my user is something like name_name (two names separated by `_`)

my passwords only contains letters and numbers.

Every time I do

```
svn checkout url
```

I get something like this

```
 svn checkout https://riouxsvn.com/svn/***
Authentication realm: <https://riouxsvn.com:443> RiouxSVN
Password for 'dell': 
Authentication realm: <https://riouxsvn.com:443> RiouxSVN
Username: name_name
Password for 'name_name': 
Authentication realm: <https://riouxsvn.com:443> RiouxSVN
Username: name_name
Password for 'name_name': 
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://riouxsvn.com/svn/***': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://riouxsvn.com)
```

'dell' is the user in my machine (I don't know why is asking me that)

After make public the repository, I checkout it (without authentification) and I cannot do the commit. This is what I'm getting

```
 svn commit
Authentication realm: <https://riouxsvn.com:443> RiouxSVN
Password for 'dell': 
Authentication realm: <https://riouxsvn.com:443> RiouxSVN
Username: name_name
Password for 'name_name': 
Authentication realm: <https://riouxsvn.com:443> RiouxSVN
Username: name_name
Password for 'name_name': 
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: MKACTIVITY of '**********590f4de6-f163-4a84-b2ef-032bda678d16': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://riouxsvn.com)
svn: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
svn:    '/media/C47A3F8A7A3F77EE/Dev/Projects/UCyG - Control de Avance de Obra/ucyg/svn-commit.tmp'
```

For safety remove the url.

I'm pretty sure that my password is ok (I can log in into the page without problems), and I don't know what to do.

I've read some questions here and outside Stackoverflow, but still no clue of why I'm getting an error of authentication

Any help will be appreciated.

If matters, my OS is Linux Mint 13 Maya 64 bits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the solution was..

change the svn repo.

Now I have account in Assembla and everything works fine.